# requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.LinearLayout during layout: running second layout pass

Tags: android, android-layout

Here i'm using frame layout when i click ,the login linearlayout is called ,here when         i try to clikc OK button ,i'm getting this warning, can anyone say how can i use the OK button event?.........

```
**my lauyout is** 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/layout_practitioner" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"       
    >  
        <ImageView 
         android:id="@+id/item_image" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:scaleType="centerCrop"
         android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescriptionContent"
         >
       </ImageView>     

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center"
     >

            <TextView             
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="@string/enter_pass_password"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_practitioner_pin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_shape"
                android:ems="6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="numberPassword"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:visibility="visible" >              

            </EditText>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pract_button"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buton_shape"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="OK" 
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                />
    </LinearLayout>


 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#bbffffff"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
     >
       <TextView android:id="@+id/item_text" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
        android:textColor="@color/text_black"    
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:textSize="25sp" 
        android:textAllCaps="true"

        > </TextView>


         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_pratiotioner_group_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/sub_title_color"   
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

my java code

```
holder.img_pract_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                    
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {                       
                        id_ = holder.img_pract_view.getId();
                        Log.d("*inside***id", ""+v.getId());
                        //holder.loginButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image clicked"+v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        holder.edit_pin.setText("");
                        holder.edit_pin.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                        holder.edit_pin.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                        holder.loginLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                 

                    }
                });


                holder.loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        holder.loginLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                        Log.d("button", "clicked");
                    }
                });
                convertView.setTag(holder);


## Heading ##
```

[image]

Comment: could you show some java code I think you are trying to load a new layout from another xml file but I see the linearlayout within the frame layout

Comment: yea now i added the part java code ,what i did here just called the login layout when imageview is clicked